# Applying math incorrectly to physics

Tags: physics, fake-proofs

I have the following argument in physics which I'm pretty sure is wrong:

Since all change in location is bounded by the speed of light times elapsed time, we can conclude that any movement is $c$-Lipschitz. And therefore the location function is continuous. But I'm pretty sure that I've heard that in quantum mechanics there are discontinuities.

I cannot find the fault in this logic, and would appreciate any help as to understanding why the logic is erroneous.

Edit:
I changed the phrasing to fit what I meant rather than what I wrote.

Comment: is there a fault?

Comment: In fact, if you assume that the speed of every body is defined at every time, you are assuming that every movement is differentiable and hence continuous.

Comment: Is there an implicit assumption in this argument that time is continuous ?

Comment: I consider location to be a function from an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: As others already commented, why do you think that movement is not continuous? Could you give a practical example of a discontinuous movement, and also give the functions that describe it (as a function of time)?

Comment: In the spirit of Lewis Carroll's Mad Hatter, functions work harder for physicists than mathematicians because we pay them better.  They are kind enough to always be uniformly continuous and analytic so you can swap integration variables, differentiate under summation and integral signs, expand in Taylor series, and many more.

Comment: I think the second law of Newton implies that distance is twice differentiable function of time so it is continuous.